# How to stub an external API in RSpec without using vcr?

Tags: ruby, rspec, twilio, stub

I've created a module that utilises the twilio-ruby gem to provide sms functionality to another object. The code works, but I'm finding it difficult to test.

```
module Sms

TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER = "+44..."

ACCOUNT_SID = 'AC0...'
AUTH_TOKEN = 'ae7...'

def send_text_message(customers_phone_number, delivery_time)
  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
  @client.messages.create(
    from: TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
    to: customers_phone_number.to_s,
    body: "Thank you! Your order was placed and will be delivered before #{delivery_time.to_s[11..15]}"
)
end

end
```

I'm able to stub out the API call using vcr, but this seems overkill for what I need to do. The most common suggestion online is to use WebMock, but when implementing this I can't get past the following error:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 # /Users/tomcoakes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/twilio-ruby-3.14.5/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/list_resource.rb:101:in `create'
```

I've 'p' inspected that twilio file and tried to mock the object it is expecting but this hasn't worked for me.

Would anyone be able to explain how to use WebMock to effectively block this post method, or alternatively is there an even simpler way to stub this test that doesn't require the use of any other gems?

Answer (score 1):

have you considered just stubbing 'send_text_message' with something like:

`ruby
expect(object).to receive(:send_text_message)`

or something similar?